# Publishing thread safe object

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

As per specifications, we can not synchronize a constructor of any object because other threads cannot see the object being created before the thread creating it has finished it. But as per JMM, during creation of an object memory can be allocated and referred to the reference variable before its states are initialized. 
So why Java should not allow synchronize method along with constructors to publish always thread safe object reference?